# Assigned as the Owner of an Azure AD application, Still Can't configure it

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

[image]

As you can see that I'm assigned as the Owner of this Azure AD app but still I'm unable to make any configuration changes to it.

ps: I am a guest user to the Subscription with contributor permissions.

So the AAD administrator made an AAD app with owner access on the subscription and added me as the owner of this application.

I logged in using this service principal still it shows the error below:

[image]

Comment: On the picture it looks like you have the access you are granted "Configuration Owner" and nothing else. What are you expecting to be able to configure that you cant?

Comment: Actually I want to use this service principal to Login as my user doesn't have the appropriate permissions to register an AAD application which is required to deploy a SPN for an automation Runbook. The administrator made this App with Owner permissions on the subscription and added me as the owner of this application, Yet my script to deploy the son for automation runbook fails. Let me show you the exact error. (I am adding the exact error in the original Question)

Comment: I think you need the role "Application Developer" in the AAD. Then the Global Admin can grant concent to the App if needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#application-developer

Comment: As you can see your code is trying to create a new app. So the user or SPN used to run the code needs to have Application Developer or some other role that allows you to create a new app.

Comment: Thank you, They Only want to give up the minimum possible Permissions to me, so can You let me know what are the minimum possible permissions required for this use case, and these roles will be assigned to the user or the AAD app ?

Comment: See my answer, either they do one of those things or you let them run the PowerShell commands for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

If the app registrations setting is set to No, only users with an administrator role may register these types of applications. See available roles and role permissions to learn about available administrator roles and the specific permissions in Azure AD that are given to each role. If your account is assigned the User role, but the app registration setting is limited to admin users, ask your administrator to either assign you one of the administrator roles that can create and manage all aspects of app registrations, or to enable users to register apps.